# NuGet config in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

Does anybody know how/where I have to execute the following line of code so that Visual Studio 2015 will not use my user profile folder as global cache for NuGet packages?

`nuget config –set globalPackagesFolder=C:\Development\NuGet\packages`

I've already tried Visual Studio's embedded Package Manager, which rejects the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anybody know how/where I have to execute the following line of code

This command line should be executed with NuGet.exe cli.

To accomplish this:

- Download the nuget.exe form [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) under the Windows x86
  Commandline tab, save this file to your local, for example,
  `D:\nuget`.
- Open a cmd, switch the path to the location where nuget.exe exists.
- Execute above command line.

[image]

After executed this command line, you can open the `NuGet.Config` in the folder `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`, following code will added in it:

```
  <config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="C:\Development\NuGet\packages" />
  </config>
```

similarly, you can also add this setting by manually.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So the default NuGet configuration also applies to Visual Studio?

Comment: @mu88, yes. Check this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior